# Multiple strings in one NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am getting multiple string from `HTMl` to one `NSString`, every time the string is replaced by a new string. i tried `NSArray` it says `NSString` is strong for array. i want all the strings store in `NSString` one by one. how can i do that ?

```
TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:nsData];
            NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='NewsPageArticle']/p/span ";
            // NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='entry']/ul/li/a";
            NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

            // 4
            NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
            for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
                // 5
                Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
                [newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

                // 6
                tutorial.title = [[element firstChild] content];
```

Comment: can you post HTMl string input which you are storing in NSString?

Comment: i have a huge code for parsing HTML

Comment: Your post is barely intelligible, but, best as I can understand it, @Sumanth has the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSMutableString` for appending string

```
NSMutableString aString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:yourHTMLString];
[aString appendString:parsedHTMLString];
```